# Retrieve selected checkboxes in an array into the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, arraylist

How can i retrieve the selected checkbox in the controller.

This is the main view where the user can choose a request access.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("addBatch_CARF", "CARF", FormMethod.Post, new { @name = "register" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div id="formAlert" class="alert alert-danger">  
        <a class="close">×</a>  
        <strong>Warning!</strong> Make sure all fields are filled and try again.
    </div>

    var catName = "";
    var displayCan = "";
    var candidates = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        if (catName != Model[i].request_category)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].request_category)
                <span class="pull-right" style="margin-right:60px;">Special Instructions</span>
            </li>
            catName = Model[i].request_category;
            displayCan = catName;
        }
        if (displayCan == Model[i].request_category)
        {
            candidates = Model[i].request_name;
            <div class="checkbox_request">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model[i].isSelected, new { @class = "is_selected" })                      
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].request_name)
                @if(Model[i].request_name == "Folder Access")
                {
                    <span class="label label-danger">Pls specify all the drive path. Note: For accessing of drives outside PETC please proceed to Online CARF</span>
                }
                <span class="pull-right">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].special_instruction)
                </span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].request_type_id)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].system_roles_id)
            </div>
         }                     
     }
     <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
         Access to:
     </li>                 
     <div id="employeeAdd">
         @{Html.RenderAction("AddRequestor"); }
     </div>                 
     <p class="request_btn">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn">Save</button>
     </p>
}
```

I have only rendered this view `AddRequestor` in selecting or adding an employee.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++){
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.CheckBox("checkbox", new { @class = "is_selected" }) 
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].FullName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].Emp_Badge_No)
                </th>
            </tr>    

    }   
</table>
```

The main goal of this is all the chosen employees must have also all the chosen request access.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addBatch_CARF(List<Request_Type> list, List<Employees_All_vw> emp, string[] checkboxes)
{
    foreach (var x in emp)
    {
        int num = 1;
        bool z = Convert.ToBoolean(num);
        if (x.checkbox == z)
        {
            //add data into CARF table
            CARF carf = new CARF();
            carf.requestor = x.Emp_Badge_No;
            carf.carf_type = "BATCH CARF";
            carf.created_by = @User.Identity.Name.Remove(0, 9).ToLower();
            carf.created_date = System.DateTime.Now;
            carf.active_flag = true;
            db.CARves.Add(carf);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int id = carf.carf_id;
            //add data into Request Access Table
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                int val = 1;
                bool y = Convert.ToBoolean(val);
                if (i.isSelected == y)
                {
                    Request_Access ra = new Request_Access();
                    ra.request_access_id = 1;
                    ra.carf_id = id;
                    ra.request_type_id = i.request_type_id;
                    ra.special_instruction = i.special_instruction;
                    ra.ra_assignee = i.system_roles_id;
                    ra.dept_approval = null;
                    ra.dept_approval_date = null;
                    ra.dept_remarks = null;
                    ra.final_approval = null;
                    ra.final_approval_date = null;
                    ra.final_remarks = null;
                    ra.acknowledge_by = null;
                    ra.acknowledge_date = null;
                    ra.journal = null;
                    ra.closed_by = null;
                    ra.closed_date = null;
                    ra.verified_by = null;
                    ra.verified_date = null;
                    db.Request_Access.Add(ra);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        TempData["MessageAlert"] = "Successfully created!";
        return RedirectToAction("Batch_CARF");
    }
}
```

I've got an error on this line `if (x.checkbox == z)`

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string[]' and 'bool'

Comment: `@Html.CheckBox("checkbox", ..)` generates multiple checkboxes with `name="checkbox"` which you then post back to `string[] checkboxes`. You code is confusing but the parameter should contain a collection of strings  - either `"True"` or `"False"` which you first need to convert to `bool` - or better just make the parameter `bool[] checkboxes`

Comment: However none of this will work correctly. `@Html.CheckBox()` generates 2 inputs, a `type="checkbox"` with `value="true"` and a `type="hidden"` with value="false"` so if its checked, both `true` and `false` post back and if its unchecked, then only `false` is posted. There is no way you can possibly match up which values belong to which item

Comment: So, how I am going to do it properly? What should I put in the `@Html.ChecckBox()`?

Comment: You have not shown your models, but `AddRequestor` needs a (say) `bool IsSelected` property and use `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)` and then you can bind to parameter `IEnumerable<AddRequestor> requestors` in the POST method.

Comment: Do I need to put `IsSelected` as a field in the database to do it?

Comment: No. You should be using view models and map to your data models.

Comment: I'll have `bool active_flag` in the db where I only queried those active employees and when `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].active_flag)`, all checkboxes are checked

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the relevance of your last comment?

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter `string[] checkboxes` contains values that are typeof `string` (either `"True"` or `"False"`) so you would need to use the `Convert.ToBoolean()` method before comparing `if (x.checkbox == z)`. However this will not work since `@Html.CheckBox("checkbox", ..)` generates 2 inputs `type="checkbox"` with `value="True"` and a `type="hidden"` with `value="False"` so if its checked, both `true` and `false` post back and if its unchecked, then only `false` is posted. There is no way you can possibly match up which values belong to which employee.

Instead create a view model to represent the selection of employees

```
public class EmployeeVM
{
  public string BadgeNumber { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your `AddRequestor()` method (assumes you have an `Employees` table)

```
public ActionResult AddRequestor()
{
  List<EmployeeVM> model = db.Employees.Where(e => e.active_flag).Select(e => new EmployeeVM
  {
    BadgeNumber = e.Emp_Badge_No,
    Name = e.FullName
  }.ToList();
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the view

```
@model List<EmployeeVM>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].BadgeNumber)
  <label>
    @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name)</span>
  </label>
}
```

And finally, in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addBatch_CARF(List<Request_Type> list, List<EmployeesVM> employees)
{
  // To get the selected employees
  IEnumerable<string> selectedEmployees = employees.Where(e => e.IsSelected);
  foreach(EmployeesVM employee in selectedEmployees)
  {
    ....
    carf.requestor = employee.BadgeNumber;
    ....
```

Comment: Well, thanks for this @Stephen. I have one question, how will I display the employee or data every time a user checked the checkbox? And no need to submit something, just every time a user checked a checkbox then it will be displayed.

Comment: Not sure I understand? What data do you need to display each time you check a checkbox?

Comment: Yes Sir. Can I display the data ?

Comment: Which data are you referring to. The partial view displays the name of all active employees (I assume that's what `active_flag` means) with a checkbox. Do you need to display some other data associated with each employee?

Comment: Yes, the partial view. Since, a lot of employees displays in the checkbox, to easily know or identify which of those employees are being checked, it would be nicer if every time a user checked an employee. It would be displayed all the checked checkboxes

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your asking. It is displaying all the checkboxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94152/discussion-between-jen143me-and-stephen-muecke).